# Node.js - getting a value from MySQL and assigning it to a variable

Tags: mysql, node.js

My query:

```
pool.query("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM `games` WHERE status IN('0','1') LIMIT 1", (err, row) => {
    if(err) return console.log("err getting the game.");
    currentGame = row[0];
    console.log(currentGame);
});
```

Current Result:

```
RowDataPacket { 'MAX(ID)': 1 }
```

Desired Result:

`1`

How do I get just the value and not include the other stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an alias to your count query, and then access it:

```
pool.query("SELECT MAX(ID) AS max_id FROM games WHERE status IN ('0','1')", (err, row) => {
    if(err) return console.log("err getting the game.");
    currentGame = row[0].max_id;
    console.log(currentGame);
});
```

Note: A max query by definition will always return only a single record result set (in the absence of `GROUP BY`), so there is no need for `LIMIT 1`.